# How to decode password by base64_decode in Android

Tags: android, passwords, password-encryption, change-password

My password come from database and it's encoded, so how can I decode it in Android side?

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("mypref", MODE_PRIVATE);
id = preferences.getString("id", "");
password=preferences.getString("password","");
```

**password** is encoded by **base64_encode**.

I want to decode that password.

I use this:

```
byte[] decodePassword;
decodePassword= Base64.decode(password, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Could you please explain "but it din't work.."?

Comment: Why do you store passwords?

Comment: My question would be: Why do you want to decode a password ? It's a security leak !! But let's say it's not a password but anything else converted to Base64, like rudolf asked, what is your current output, and what did you expected ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```
byte[] decodePassword;
decodePassword= Base64.decode(password, Base64.DEFAULT);
String your_password = new String(decodePassword, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```